# Unable to loop through cURL command

Tags: bash, shell, variable-substitution

I am able to execute individual cURL commands using,

```
curl -u user:password -v -XPOST -H 'Content-type: text/xml' -d '<featureType><name>quadrella_indica</name></featureType>' http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/opengeo/datastores/species/featuretypes
```

But I need to loop through the entire list of shp file and so,

```
for f in *.shp
   do 
   a=${f,,};
   curl -u user:password -v -XPOST -H 'Content-type: text/xml' -d    '<featureType><name>${a%.*}</name></featureType>' http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/opengeo/datastores/species/featuretypes 
done
```

But unlike the success that I receive when I am adding them individually, I receive an error when I loop through,

```
* About to connect() to localhost port 8080 (#0)
*   Trying ::1... connected
* Server auth using Basic with user 'admin'
> POST /geoserver/rest/workspaces/opengeo/datastores/species/featuretypes HTTP/1.1
> Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46Z2Vvc2VydmVy
> User-Agent: curl/7.22.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.22.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1 zlib/1.2.3.4 libidn/1.23 librtmp/2.3
> Host: localhost:8080
> Accept: */*
> Content-type: text/xml
> Content-Length: 47
> 
* upload completely sent off: 47out of 47 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
< Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
< Content-Type: text/plain
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Date: Sun, 25 Nov 2012 18:19:31 GMT
< Connection: close
< 
* Closing connection #0
Trying to create new feature type inside the store, but no attributes were specified
```

I am doing something wrong in the looping as the individual cURLs work just fine. How can I correct it?

Answer (score 1):

Variables are not expanded inside single quotes, use double quotes instead:

```
curl ... "...${var%.*}..."
```

Comment: So I executed this command, `for f in *.shp; do curl -u user:password -v -XPOST -H 'Content-type: text/xml' -d "<featureType><name>${f%.*}_poly</name></featureType>" http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/opengeo/datastores/species/featuretypes; done` but the output is still the same

Comment: Try to add `--trace-ascii -` to see the body of the requests.

Comment: not sure where to add it?? i m still a newbie

Comment: You can put it in place of the -v switch for instance.

Comment: `-v` is already present